# how to stop bind in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I hava a checkbox ,the model `status.useJoin` also bind the `div`.

```html
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="status.useJoin"  ng-click="toggleJoin($event);" >

 <div ng-if="status.useJoin"> show area</div>
```

when `status.useJoin` is `true` ,will show `div`.

My question is ,when I want to prevent the default action of the checkbox. I will write function `toggleJoin` like this.

```js
  $scope.toggleJoin = function (dimension,$event) {
   if (status.useJoin) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      return; 
   }
 }
```

the checkbox action is stopped ,but `status.useJoin` is still modified. How can I stop the bind?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="status.useJoin"  ng-disabled="onYourDisableCondition();" >


$scope. onYourDisableCondition = function () {
   if (status.useJoin) { //Add your additional conditions     
      return true; 
   }
 }
```